# call vimeo video using ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this example code, but i believe when i call the ajax function that  is not loaded. How can i load an external script as below? Thanks

```
       <?php if (is_ajax_request()): ?>
        <div id="movie5" class="movie"></div>
            <script>
                 var swf = swfobject.embedSWF("http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=35014154&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0", "movie5", "500", "281", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", { api:1, player_id:"movie5" }, { allowfullscreen:true, allowscriptaccess:'always' });
            </script>
```

Comment: jQuery usually executes scripts in fragments loaded via ajax, the problem must be something else. Are you sure that swfobject is defined somewhere?

Comment: well if i insert that swfObject in the main page i get the video so swfObject is loaded fine, but i need to get this vimeo form anothe rpag usig a simpe ajax call: var url = this.href + " .content"; infoBox.load(url);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i came up with using this:

In the main page I have a  element which i then populate and replace with the iframe

Main page:

```
<span class="video clearfix" data-vimeoid="<?php echo the_field('vimeo') ?>"></span>
```

Content page to be loaded:

```
var url = this.href + " .content";
  var videoSpan = infoBox.find("span.video");
  var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
            'frameborder' : 0,
            'width' : '692',
            'height' : '389',
            'src' : 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ videoSpan.data("vimeoid") +'?autoplay=0&api=1'
    });
  videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a ajax call for this? It is pure javascript just execute it and make sure the required library is included on the page. Try this.

```
if($('movie5').length == 0){
    $('<div id="movie5" class="movie" />')
    .appendTo(document.body);//Specify the container where you need this player
}

var swf = swfobject.embedSWF("http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=35014154&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0", "movie5", "500", "281", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", { api:1, player_id:"movie5" }, { allowfullscreen:true, allowscriptaccess:'always' });
```

**Update:**

Ideally the script which is a part of html content is executed by jQuery when you use `html`, `append` etc methods. It is not working then there must be some js error on the page.

Alternative way which you can try is. Just get the html content through `ajax` call and execute the script to initialize the player after you set the html content inside `ajax` success handler.

Try this.

```
$.ajax({
   ..
   success: function(data){
         $('.info').html(data);

         //Now initialize the player
         var swf = swfobject.embedSWF("http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=35014154&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0", "movie5", "500", "281", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", { api:1, player_id:"movie5" }, { allowfullscreen:true, allowscriptaccess:'always' });

   }  
})
```

Comment: because this is different content on different pages which i load with ajax

Comment: The see the content contains just a div and script to initialize the player. Which can be easily done by the script I provided and avoid ajax calls too.

Comment: it doesn't load the video into the box if i say:  $('<div id="movie5" class="movie" />').appendTo(".info"); with .info be my div

Comment: If the div is appended and the player initialization code works fine the it should load.

Comment: this is the live: http://www.robertomarras.com/wptest/

i'm trying this in the main page and no in the page that has to be loaded and i get no video:

if($('movie5').lenght == 0){
    $(".info").append(swf);
}
var swf = swfobject.embedSWF("http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=<?php the_field('vimeo'); ?>&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0", "movie5", "692", "389", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", { api:1, player_id:"movie5" }, { allowfullscreen:true, allowscriptaccess:'always' });

Comment: What is `$(".info").append(swf);`? What are you appending a JavaScript variable?

Comment: Hey there is a typo in `lenght`, change it to `length' it will work.

Comment: that was a mistake, sorry. I have just tried to copy and paste exactly your bit and i get no div appended

Comment: I could load the video through console on your site. Correct that typo you should be good to go.

Comment: it works! now i need to append it in the right box only when the content has loaded via ajax tho, how to?

Comment: Where do you load the ajax content?

Comment: i load the ajax content into <div class=".info">

Comment: After loading the content just execute the script `var swf = swfobject.embedSWF("http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=35014154&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=0&amp;show_byline=0&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;fullscreen=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;loop=0", "movie5", "500", "281", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", { api:1, player_id:"movie5" }, { allowfullscreen:true, allowscriptaccess:'always' });`

Comment: obviously i need to append it ONLY when I load the other content and not before

Comment: Also make sure you dont send that script in  the ajax response.

Comment: but how do i check when the content is loaded? the reason why i wanted to have that in the content to be loaded was to load all together, in your solution i now need to find out when content has been loaded, how can i?

Comment: You don't append the script you execute it.

Comment: Check my edited answer I have added the code for your understanding.

Comment: should i put that in the main page or in the content page to be loaded?

Comment: well if i put that into the page to be loaded .. i don't get the video while if i put it in the main page it crashes

Comment: Please use one of the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) for extended discussions.

Comment: Where do you make the ajax call?

Comment: what code? $.ajax({    success: function(data){
         $('.info').html(data); ? that doesn't work if i do it